# Is the word despite always used to show contrast?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

I dont think so

What about this sentence?

Despite being a king you should not misuse your power

Here there is no contrast or irony 
the meaning is clear and straightforward

am I wrong?

but the dictionary says that the preposition despite is always used to show contrast

Answer (score 1):

Your sentence is not a valid use of **despite**. It would be valid to say 
"Despite everyone deferring to you, your powers are limited." or
"Despite being a king, you can do little without help from your subjects."

Comment: how about although

Comment: although you're a king but you should not misuse your power